# Continuum percolation in 1d

Tags: pr.probability, random-graphs, percolation

What is known about continuum percolation in 1d?

By this, I mean, for $d \in \mathbb{N}$, the Poisson-Boolean model of disks of radius $r_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ with centres arranged randomly in $[0,1]^{d}$, with a Poisson number of disks at density $\lambda$ per unit volume, taking the case $d=1$. A pair of disks is connected if they overlap.

In site percolation on the integer lattice in 1d, the critical site occupation probability $p_c=1$, otherwise the chain of sites will break somewhere.

But in 1d continuum percolation, can $r_0(\lambda)$ scale slowly enough to zero as $\lambda \to \infty$ for the probability of a break goes to zero?

Comment: Whatever $r_0$ and $\lambda$ are, there will be infinitely many gaps of size bigger than $2r_0$, so that there is no percolation.

Comment: So basically, only if $2r_0$ is the width of the domain do you get percolation.

Comment: OK - sorry - I hadn't read the question properly. So you are looking at a finite segment of the line, namely [0,1] rather than all of $\mathbb R$. My answer applies to the infinite case. So in the finite case, there should be some sort of phase transition, I think. I can't tell you exactly what it is immediately though.

Comment: You're answer is correct. So, if the ratio $r_0/w$, where $w$ is the domain width, goes to a constant, is that may be sufficient for percolation?

Comment: Can you see any literature on this? Or has it not been studied?

Comment: I'm not understanding here. I thought $w$ was fixed and you are looking at how $r$ should scale with $\lambda$. (Certainly $w$ may as well be fixed because changing $w$ by a factor of $t$ is equivalent to changing $r$ by a factor of $t$ and $\lambda$ by a factor of $1/t$).

Comment: Yes sorry, just set $w$ to 1. I mean simply that as $\lambda \to \infty$, you at least need $r_0$ a strictly non-zero fraction of the domain width, i.e. does not go to zero.

Comment: I'm really not expert in this field. But I'm sure there is literature if you look for it. Probably the 1D case is such that you can derive a pretty reliable estimate by simple calculations (this is much harder in 2D and higher).

Comment: So set $w=1$. I prefer to think about $\lambda(r)$ rather than $r(\lambda)$. Of course one is just the inverse of the other. So given $r$, you want it to be very likely there is another centre at a distance in the range $[r,2r]$. How likely? Likely enough that this can be continued for $1/r$ steps. So: you want $(1-e^{-r\lambda})^{1/r}$ to be close to 1.

Answer (score 1):

See for example this paper.

[Covering by random intervals and one-dimensional continuum percolation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01042611)

C. Domb, J. Stat. Phys. Vol. 55(1-2), 1989

and also

[Exact solution of a one-dimensional continuum percolation model](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.55.3878)

A. Drory, Phys. Rev. E Vol. 55(4), 1997

among other works, including many by the second author above.